# Is TO_TIME function broken for inputs with precision higher than second?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is [TO_TIME](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_time.html) function broken for inputs with precision higher than second? I'm trying to convert number of time units (millis, micros or nanos) passed from midnight to TIME type.

For example, I think there are 86399100 milliseconds between midnight and 23:59:59.100 but following query

```sql
select to_varchar(to_time('86399100')::time, 'hh24:mi:ss.FF9')
```

yields `23:45:00.000000000`. Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look under Usage notes in the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_time.html)

> After the string is converted to an integer, the integer is treated as
> a number of seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds after
> the start of the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 UTC).
>
> > - If the integer is less than `31536000000` (the number of milliseconds    in a year), then the value is treated as a number of
> >   seconds.
> > - If the value is greater than or equal to `31536000000` and less than    `31536000000000`, then the value is treated as milliseconds.

Your input of `86399100` is less than `31536000000`  therefore it is treated as seconds.